# Creating a file based on output from a find -exec

Tags: shell-script, find, python

I'm writing a shell script to batch validate (w3c validator) a load of HTML files.

I'm using https://github.com/mozilla/html5-lint which provides a python script to do the actual validation work.

The command I'm currently running is:

```
find . -type f -name "*q2*.html" -print -exec ~/Downloads/html5-lint-master/html5check.py -e {} \;
```

This is working and producing the output in the form:

```
The document is valid HTML5 + ARIA + SVG 1.1 + MathML 2.0 (subject to the utter previewness of this service).
```

When valid.

Or a list of errors - e.g.:

```
Error: Attribute “placeholder” is only allowed when the input type is “email”, “number”, “password”, “search”, “tel”, “text”, or “url”.
From line 53, column 13; to line 53, column 92
Error: Attribute “placeholder” is only allowed when the input type is “email”, “number”, “password”, “search”, “tel”, “text”, or “url”.
From line 57, column 13; to line 57, column 95
There were errors. (Tried in the text/html mode.)
```

Based on the response I'm hoping to create a file in the same folder as the HTML file called either valid.txt or invalid.txt containing the output.

Any tips on how best to achieve this?

Comment: Are there multiple html files (matching the find pattern) in the same folder, and if so, what do you want to happen then? Have a combined "valid.txt" or "invalid.txt", or differently named ones, or ...?

Comment: I'd recommend writing a separate shell script to run `html5check.py` and store its output, rather than trying to fit this into a `find -exec` command. (Then you can use `-exec` to run the script.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```bash
find . -type f -name '*q2*.html' -execdir sh -c '
    your/script "$1" > invalid.txt
    grep -q "Error:" invalid.txt || mv invalid.txt valid.txt
' sh {} \;
```

Note that you will be overwriting the `(in)valid.txt` file if you have more than one html files matching your `find`, into the same directory. You would probably like to include `$(basename "$1")` into the output filename to make its name unique per directory.

With `-execdir`, the command is executed into the directory of every file found.

`grep -q` silently exits with failure (`1`) if no `Error:` found, so the command after `||` is executed. If error found, `grep` exits with success (`0`) and the `mv` is not executed.

You probably want to add some more for catching cases like some error of your script. Also ensure that the search pattern cannot exist for a valid file.

---

Another approach, independent of what messages your program is printing, is to use exit codes.

`import sys` to your python script and use `sys.exit(0)` for a valid file, or `sys.exit(42)` for an invalid one. After execution, you parse the exit code (`$?`) and decide what to do.

See also: https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html

Example:

```
your/script "$1" > output.txt
result=$?
((result == 0)) && do stuff for valid file
((result == 42)) && do stuff for invalid file
```

Comment: Thank you - this answer worked just as is, but gave me the basis I needed to adapt to my needs also. Really appreciate the detailed explanations.

Comment: welcome and thanks for your comment.